# Finding upper and lower limits of integral

Tags: calculus

Find the values of $a$ and $b$ where $a < b$, such that $\displaystyle\int_a^b e^{-x^2}(1-x^2)\,dx$ has the largest value. Justify your answers. 
I tried integration by parts by integrating $(1-x^2)$ and differentiating $e^{-x^2}$. But it just got worst.

Comment: Did you try setting the partial derivatives with respect to $a$ and $b$ equal to $0$?

Answer (score 3):

If you know multi-variable calculus, we can approach your problem in the following way:

Define 
$$f(a,b) = \int_a^b e^{-x^2}(1-x^2)\,dx = \int_0^b e^{-x^2}(1-x^2)\,dx - \int_0^ae^{-x^2}(1-x^2)\,dx$$
Since you want to find $a$ and $b$ with $a<b$ such that the integral is maximized, we'll need to compute the critical points of $f(a,b)$; hence we see that
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial a} = -e^{-a^2}(1-a^2),\qquad\frac{\partial f}{\partial b} = e^{-b^2}(1-b^2)$$
and thus
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial a} = 0 \implies 1-a^2=0 \implies a=\pm 1,\qquad \frac{\partial f}{\partial b}=0 \implies 1-b^2=0 \implies b=\pm 1.$$
The only pair that satisfies the constraint $a<b$ is the point $(-1,1)$.

Now, we see that

$$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial a^2} = 2ae^{-a^2}(2-a^2),\quad \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial b^2} = -2be^{-b^2}(2-b^2),\quad \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial a\partial b} = 0$$

and hence

$$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial a^2}(-1,1) = -2e^{-1},\quad \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial b^2} (-1,1) = -2e^{-1},\quad \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial a\partial b}(-1,1) = 0.$$

Thus, We see that

$$D=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial a^2}(-1,1)\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial b^2}(-1,1) - \left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial a\partial b}(-1,1)\right)^2 = 4e^{-2}>0$$

Furthermore, $\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial a^2}(-1,1) = -2e^{-1}<0$; therefore, by the second partials test, the point $(-1,1)$ maximizes $f(a,b)$.

Thus, $\displaystyle\int_a^b e^{-x^2}(1-x^2)\,dx$ is maximized when $a=-1$ and $b=1$.

Comment: No problem. Another test (which I favour), is the definicy (noun of "definite"??) of $Hf$, the Hessian of $f$. Since $Hf(-1,1)$ is equal to $- \frac 2 e I_2$, you have $Hf(-1,1) \prec 0$ without further calculations.

Answer (score 1):

The Function does not have an elementary anti-derivative. Use estimates instead. In fact, since
$$(1-x^2) > 0 \Leftrightarrow x \in [-1,1]$$
and $e^{-x^2} > 0 \quad \forall\ x$, the maximum is attained at $(a,b) = (-1,1)$ and is equal to
$$\int_{-1}^1 e^{-x^2} (1-x^2) dx = 2 \int_0^1 e^{-x^2} (1-x^2) dx = \frac 1 e + \frac {\sqrt \pi} 2{\rm erf}(1) $$
Where
$$\frac {\sqrt \pi} 2 {\rm erf}(1) = \int_0^1 e^{-x^2} dx$$

Comment: what's erf(1) ?

Comment: @Fred That's the [error funcion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html). The non-elementary part about the integral ;-)

Comment: I got it so this function is a discontinous function at x=1 right?

Comment: Nope, it's even analytic on $\mathbb C$ (entire). But it cannot be represented as a combination of somewhat "elementary functions" like trigs, polynomials, hyperbolics, ...